# How to add Unique ID number to a list if rows contain a consecutive sequence (Arcpy)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, address

I am trying to use an Arcpy Python code to identify the Unique ID number for streets that contain consecutive addresses and ignore rows that do not. For example:

```
FULLST  |  LOR  |  HIR  |  UID
Gate    |   1   |  200  |   1
Gate    |  201  |  300  |   2
Smith   |   1   |  100  |   3
Smith   |  350  |  400  |   4
Smith   |  401  |  500  |   5
```

In this example I need to add UID numbers 1, 2, 4, and 5 to a list. The code I have so far (from a comment by @dslamb [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190075/how-to-find-identical-street-names-with-consecutively-numbered-addresses-using-a/190338?noredirect=1#comment288723_190338)) will grab 2 and 5, but not 1 and 4. For some reason it will not add the first street UID in the consecutive sequence.

```
streetlist = []
sc = arcpy.SearchCursor(STMS, None, None, "FULLST; LOR; HIR; MCN; OEN; UID", None)
previousSt = None
previousHIR = None
previousMCN = None
previousOEN = None
for row in sc:
    if not previousSt:
        previousSt = row.getValue("FULLST")
        previousHIR = row.getValue("HIR")
        previousMCN = row.getValue("MCN")
        previousOEN = row.getValue("OEN")
    else:
        if previousSt == row.getValue("FULLST") and previousMCN == row.getValue("MCN") and previousOEN == row.getValue("OEN"):
            if (row.getValue("LOR")-1) == previousHIR or row.getValue("LOR") < previousHIR:
                streetlist.append(row.getValue("UID"))
                previousHIR = row.getValue("HIR")
            else:
                previousHIR = row.getValue("HIR")
        else:
            previousSt = row.getValue("FULLST")
            previousHIR = row.getValue("HIR")  
            previousMCN = row.getValue("MCN") 
            previousOEN = row.getValue("OEN") 
del previousHIR
del previousMCN
del previousOEN
del previousSt
del sc
del row
```

I am using ArcGIS 10.2, ArcInfo License level

Comment: Step 1: Use `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`. Step 2: Use a dictionary to store previously found values.  Both will improve performance.

Comment: @Vince I don't have the data access module, so I am unable to use the arcpy.da codes.

Comment: If you're using 10.2, you have DA Cursors (they were introduced at 10.1)

Comment: Please **edit* your question to state *in the body* what software you are using (both version and license level).

Comment: @Vince I was wrong, I do have access to data access. In the past when I tried using commands from that module nothing would work. Obviously just user error.

Comment: Did you try putting them into a dictionary, then put into a list that can be sorted?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/125400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified the code I provided [originally](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190075/how-to-find-identical-street-names-with-consecutively-numbered-addresses-using-a/190338?noredirect=1#comment288723_190338), hopefully with what you need. I'm using the da module, and switched the list to a dictionary where the keys are the street name and value is a list of the ids. I think you were primarily missing the first id whenever it switched over to a new street.

```
streetlist = {}
with arcpy.SearchCursor("G/MSAG/MergedTable",["FULLST","LOR","HIR", "MCN", "OEN" "UID"],sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY FULLST,LOR')) as sc:
    previousSt = None
    previousHIR = None
    previousMCN = None
    previousOEN = None
    for row in sc:
        if not previousSt:
            previousSt = row[0]
            previousHIR = row[2]
            previousMCN = row[3]
            previousOEN = row[4]
            streetlist[previousSt]=[row[5]]
        else:
            if previousSt == row[0] and previousMCN == row[3] and previousOEN == row[4]:
                if row[1]<=previousHIR:
                    streetlist[previousSt].append(row[5])
                previousHIR = row[1]
            else:

                previousSt = row[0]
                previousHIR = row[2]
                previousMCN = row[3]
                previousOEN = row[4]
                streetlist[previousSt]=[row[5]]
```

If you want to get the list of ids for each street.

```
for k,v in streetlist.iteritems():
    print k #this is the street name
    print v #this is the list of ids.
```

You could also try this to make use of the dictionary's unique key feature and reduce the code. Instead of the if in keys, you could use a try/except.

```
streetlist = {}
with arcpy.SearchCursor("G/MSAG/MergedTable",["FULLST","LOR","HIR", "MCN", "OEN" "UID"],sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY FULLST,LOR')) as sc:
    previousHIR = None
    for row in sc:
        keystring = "%s%s%s%s"%(row[0],row[2],row[3],row[4])
        if not previousHIR:
            previousHIR = row[2]
            streetlist[keystring]=[row[5]]
        else:
            if keystring in streetlist.keys():
                if row[1]<=previousHIR:
                    streetlist[keystring].append(row[5])
                previousHIR = row[1]
            else:
                previousHIR = row[2]
                streetlist[keystring]=[row[5]]
```

Some of the commenters above may also have some speed improvement suggestions.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response but I got tied up with completing some work. Thank you for all your help and suggestions, especially showing me how to search a previous row and the Unique ID idea.

Comment: Another resolution I found was to do this after the first streetlist.append: "if row.getValue("UID") in streetlist and previousUID not in streetlist: streetlist2.append(previousUID)" I found it necessary to place the first connected street in a sequence into a separate street list because it needed a separate identification later on.